# Implementing URL slugs in Magento

Tags: url, magento, slug

How can I implement a "slug" (I believe is the right term) in the URL? Say the URL is

```
www.example.com/module/controller/action1/123
```

or

```
www.example.com/module/controller/action1/123/abc
```

and I want my `action1` controller action method hit, and I want to be able to access the value `123`, or even `123` and `abc`, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function action1Action()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data    = $request->getParams();
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses next scheme to access values in url (aside from normal GET request):

```
www.example.com/module/controller/action1/[key]/[value]/[key2]/[value2]
```

In the controller method `action1Action` you'll use

```
$value1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('[key1]'); // [value1]
$value2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('[key2]'); // [value2]
```